# Possible Choice Function for Collection of Non-Empty Subsets of Real Numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

If a step doesn’t choose a number, proceed to the next.

Note: the phrase a’s *distance to* b or $d(a, b)$ in this post means $|a - b|$, where $|x|$ is the absolute value function.
Note 2: as used in this post, the phrase A *is dense around* b means that the set of the distances of elements of A to B has no least element.

Note: as used in this post, the phrase $a \bmod b$ means the distance from the largest integer multiple of B smaller than a to a, or if there exists $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a = nb$, then 0.

Step 1: If there exists $n \in \mathbb E$ such that $|n| \leq |w|$ for any other $w \in \mathbb E$, choose $n$. (if we are to proceed, $\mathbb E$ has no smallest element with respect to distance to $0$)

Step 2: If there exists $n \in \mathbb E$ such that $|1 - n| \leq |1 - w|$ for any other $w \in \mathbb E$, choose $n$. (if we are to proceed, $\mathbb E$ has no smallest element with respect to distance to $1$)

Step 3: Set $a = 0$, $b = 1$. Call the interval $[a, b]$ $I$. If $P = \mathbb Z \cap I \cap E$, set $a = a - 1$, $b = b + 1$. Repeat until $I$ is non-empty.
Call the set of all real numbers contained in I that are also members of $\mathbb E$ as $P$. If $|P| = 1$, choose its only element. (if we are to proceed, $|P| = 2$)

Step 4: If $P$ has a maximum, choose it. (if we are to proceed, $P$ is dense around its supremum)

Step 5: If P has a minimum, choose it. (if we are to proceed, $P$ is dense around its infimum)

Step 6: Define a function $λ(s, x, m) = x \bmod m^{-s}$. Repeat the following increasing s until you choose a number:

a. Set m = e.

b. For all numbers n that are elements of P, plot $(λ(s, n, m), n)$, and if multiple n cause the same $λ(s, n, m)$, then choose the greatest as the point to plot. An infinite conflict cannot occur since the interval is finite and $λ(s, x, m)$ is periodic with a finite period. —> (P is dense around every number $k$ where $k mod m^{-s} = 0$.)

c. If there is a point with the greatest distance from 0 or the most extreme x-value, choose the height of that point, which will be in E because it’s also in P.

d. If m = e, set m = 2, and go to step b. Otherwise, continue.

**Incomplete and non-rigorous** proof that Step 6 will always terminate:

($m$ can be $e$ or $2$)

If $P$ contains any intervals then $m^{-s}$ will eventually be smaller than the size of the interval and the endpoints of the plot of (λ(s, n, m), n) will be in P.

Call the set of all the numbers that $P$ is dense around $D$. Now, for every $M \in D$, there must be infinitely many points in $P$ around $M$, otherwise it would be possible to loop over each point and determine its distance to $M$ and find the minimum, which would violate the definition of dense around. For Step 6 to not terminate for some $s$, the following are required:

- For some $M$, $M \bmod m^{-s} = 0$, so that there can be no least or greatest point $n \in P$ with respect to $λ(s, n, m)$.
- There must be no $n \in P$ such that $n\bmod m^{-s} = 0$, otherwise it would be the least in the interval.

These conditions become untenable as the $m^{-s}$ becomes smaller and smaller and each successive value is linearly independent with the alternate value of $m$ (and the previous value of $s$, in the case of $m = e$).
(This needs a rigorous proof).

Comment: you need to proofread your question.

Comment: It's not clear what your process is exactly. What, for example, would it do if applied to the set of irrational numbers?

Comment: @NoahSchweber it would go all the way to step 6, with $P = [0,1]$. It would start step 6 again with $m = e$ and $s = 1$. On b, since $2e^{-1}$ is irrational and between $[0, 1]$, when plotting $(λ(, , ), )$ with $n=2e^{-1}$, step c would choose $2e^{-1}$ (because  $λ(1, 2e^{-1}, e^{-1}) = 0$ and 0 is an extreme of [0, $e^{-1}$]) and the algorithm would terminate.

Comment: OK, what about the set of all nonzero rational multiples of $\sqrt{2}$ (which does not include $e$, and which consists only of irrational numbers)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't think that step 6 will terminate with that setup, now that I think about it. I already know this is impossible but thank you for finding a counterexample

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm seems convolution and unreadable. But without even reading it, I can happily tell you that it won't work.

If you can describe a choice function for arbitrary sets of reals, then you can prove that the real numbers can be well-ordered without using the Axiom of Choice. We know that this is not the case. Case in point, Paul Cohen proved that if $\sf ZF$ is consistent, then $\sf ZF+\Bbb R$ cannot be well-ordered is consistent as well.

But wait, there's more! It gets worse! You cannot even prove that there is a choice function from *countable* sets of reals.

Comment: haha thats ok, I've never even dealt with  before. I read the Wikipedia page for the Axiom of Choice and saw this line: "However, no choice function is known for the collection of all non-empty subsets of the real numbers (if there are non-constructible reals). In that case, the axiom of choice must be invoked." It was extremely unclear what "(if there are non-constructible reals)" had to do with anything, so I ignored it. I just tried to describe a function that could do that even though I have no experience.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Constructible set is a technical term, it refers to Gödel's constructible universe. These sets have a canonical well order, so there is a canonical choice function. It's not accurate that if non constructible reals exist, then AC must be invoked, but it's a reasonable non-technical approximation of it.